# android button setPressed after onClick

Tags: android, button, state

yesterday I noticed the possibility to integrate Fragments in older API Levels through the Compatibility package, but thats not really essential for the question. :)

I have a Button with an OnClickListener

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
        button.setPressed(true);
    }
});
```

Because of the actual clicking, it is shown as pressed and after releasing the click, the button state is not pressed and stays that way.

Is there a simple way that keeps the button state pressed after releasing?
First thing I can think of would be some sort of timer, but that seems unreasonable.

Comment: use `setSelected(boolean state)`

Comment: Hi strem - could you please list exactly how you fixed it?  Do you mean you want the button to display pressed for a set time until the event is complete?  Or reset the pressed button?  Anyway, please show your solution because the solution you selected below was wrong ..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep the button states in xml file under drawable folder, then used as background for button.
For example:

```
 android:background="@drawable/buttonstate"
```

buttonstate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/back_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/back" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: not quite what i hoped for, but thanks nevertheless! got it working now with button.setSelected(true) and definining a drawable for that state

Comment: not what the user asked, doesnt solve the problem. This answer really should not be approved.

Comment: I agree with Chuck - strem - please post an example of how you did this with setSelected(true) if you managed to achieve it that way.  Does the button return to the normal state after the action is complete?

Comment: @strem checkout my solution below

Answer (score 25):

Just to note this is because Android is changing the `setPressed` both before and after your `onClickEvent`, so changing it yourself has no effect. Another way to get around this is to use the `onTouchEvent`.

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // show interest in events resulting from ACTION_DOWN
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) return true;

        // don't handle event unless its ACTION_UP so "doSomething()" only runs once.
        if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) return false;

        doSomething();
        button.setPressed(true);                    
        return true;
   }
});
```

Comment: Martin, I like your answer very much. However, when I click in the notification area or in the options menu, the pressed state goes away. Do you have any idea of what is going on?

Answer (score 14):

Use `ToggleButton` instead of `Button`.

```xml
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/topping_selector"
    android:checked="false"
    android:textOff="Topping2"
    android:textOn="Topping2" />
```

topping_selector.xml:

```xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_topping_on" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_topping_off" />

</selector>
```

Answer (score 4):

Better solution:

In xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_activated="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_selected"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image_not_selected"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And  in java:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   v.setActivated(!v.isActivated());
}
```

Comment: Haha. Too many lines for simple task: ```v.setActivated(!v.isActivated())``` But thanks anyway

Comment: if this is the logic then you dont need a selector to..  simply toogle things on your own . bad solution'

Answer (score 3):

You can use **android.os.Handler** class. Ugly, but works also:

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        doSomething();
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setPressed(true);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to extend `Button` and override `setPressed(boolean pressed)` method so you can handle platform calls from the `onClickEvent` using a flag, for example changing the boolean pressed parameter depending on your needs.

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
   boolean isSelected = false;  //this is your flag
   @Override
   public void setPressed(boolean pressed) {
       if(isSelected) {
           //here you change the parameter so it stays pressed
           super.setPressed(true);
           return;
       }
       super.setPressed(pressed);
   }

   public void setIsSelected(boolean selected) {
       this.isSelected = selected;
   }

   public MyButton(Context context) {
       super(context);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used, It also works on android 7.0 at the moment.

**YourActivity.java**

```
public void onStandbyStart(String message) {
    startStandbyBtn.setActivated(true);
}

public void onBackOnline(String message) {
    startStandbyBtn.setActivated(false);
}
```

**YourActivityLayout**

```
<Button
        ...
        style="@style/generic_btn_style"
        ... />
```

**values/styles.xml**

```
    <style name="generic_btn_style" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical|center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/generic_btn</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/selector_white_black</item>
        <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
        <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
</style>
```

**drawable/generic_btn.xml**
This selector chooses the button background. I use the pressed as the activated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/generic_btn_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/generic_btn_pressed" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/generic_btn_pressed" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/generic_btn_focused" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/generic_btn_enabled" android:state_enabled="true" />
</selector>
```

**color/selector_black_white**
Here I set the text color. In my case, I need to pick the textcolor black when pressed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="#fff" android:state_pressed="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="#fff" android:state_activated="true" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:color="#000" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```