# Android button stay pressed / radio group

Tags: java, android

I am working on a simple converter between Decimal/Hex/Binary and have run into an issue I can't seem to solve. This is the layout I am more or less aiming for.

[image]

What I am here is when one of the buttons is pressed, it stays pressed to indicate which conversion you are currently working with. Now I have looked everywhere and it doesn't seem there is a good way of doing this, or I haven't found it at least.

What would be the best way to go about this? is there someway to just use buttons and have them stay in their "pressed" state when they are clicked? By this I only need the color of the pressed button to show. Or is there a way of doing this with some type of radio group, where the radio buttons have the same style as a regular button?

Comment: radio group is more suitable in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ... do a call to your conversion code here ....

        button.setPressed(true);
        return true;
    }
});
```

For more info: [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPressed%28boolean%29) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975168/android-button-setpressed-after-onclick)

Comment: Is there anyway to do something like this, but have it so that I don't lose the setPressed after the method ends?

Comment: @SeanCallahan The `button` should stay in the pressed state until the `Activity` is reload or you make a `button.setPressed(false)` call. What have you tried?

Comment: @Trigger That works actually! This is great. One last question you might be able to help me with. Is there anyway to check if the button is in a pressed state somewhere else in my code?

Comment: @SeanCallahan Sure, as the [developer docs says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#isPressed%28%29) - you can use `button.isPressed()`