# Android simple program - SeekBar not being created

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, seekbar

I'm working on my first android app to independently control 20 RGB LED's and I'm just working on the basic GUI structure at the moment.  My first pane works almost perfectly (the setPressed method isn't doing what I had hoped that it would and that class isn't optimized yet) but my second pane isn't showing the objects that I created.  Here's my code for my first and second panes:

activity_controller.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Controller"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button0"
            android:onClick="toggleButton0"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button1"
            android:onClick="toggleButton1"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button2"
            android:onClick="toggleButton2"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button3"
            android:onClick="toggleButton3"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button4"
            android:onClick="toggleButton4"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button5"
            android:onClick="toggleButton5"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button6"
            android:onClick="toggleButton6"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAll"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonAll"
            android:onClick="selectAll"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button7"
            android:onClick="toggleButton7"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button8"
            android:onClick="toggleButton8"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSet"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonSet"
            android:onClick="setColor"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button9"
            android:onClick="toggleButton9"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button10"
            android:onClick="toggleButton10"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonOff"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonOff"
            android:onClick="turnOff"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button11"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button11"
            android:onClick="toggleButton11"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row4"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button12"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button12"
            android:onClick="toggleButton12"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonBuiltIn"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/buttonBuiltIn"
            android:onClick="builtIns"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button13"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button13"
            android:onClick="toggleButton13"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/row6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/row5"
        style="?android:attr/buttonBarStyle">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button14"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button14"
            android:onClick="toggleButton14"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button15"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button15"
            android:onClick="toggleButton15"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button16"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button16"
            android:onClick="toggleButton16"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button17"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button17"
            android:onClick="toggleButton17"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button18"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button18"
            android:onClick="toggleButton18"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button19"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button19"
            android:onClick="toggleButton19"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleToggle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Controller.java:

```
package com.example.lightcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;


public class Controller extends Activity {
    public final static String SELECTED_BUTTONS = "com.mycompany.myfirstapp.BUTTONS";
    public final static boolean[] selectedButtons = new boolean[20];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_controller);
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 20) {
            selectedButtons[i]=false;
            i++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_controller, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void toggleButton0(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[0]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[0] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[0] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton1(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[1]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[1] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[1] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton2(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[2]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[2] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[2] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton3(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[3]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[3] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[3] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton4(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[4]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[4] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[4] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton5(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[5]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[5] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[5] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton6(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[6]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[6] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[6] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton7(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[7]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[7] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[7] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton8(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[8]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[8] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[8] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton9(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[9]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[9] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[9] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton10(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[10]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[10] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[10] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton11(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[11]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[11] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[11] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton12(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[12]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[12] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[12] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton13(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[13]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[13] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[13] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton14(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[14]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[14] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[14] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton15(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[15]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[15] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[15] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton16(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[16]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[16] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[16] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton17(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[17]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[17] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[17] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton18(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[18]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[18] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[18] = false;
        }
    }

    public void toggleButton19(View view) {
        if (!selectedButtons[19]) {
            view.setPressed(true);
            selectedButtons[19] = true;
        } else {
            view.setPressed(false);
            selectedButtons[19] = false;
        }
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void setColor(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(SELECTED_BUTTONS, selectedButtons);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

activity_display_message.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".DisplayMessageActivity"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/redSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:max="255"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/greenSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/redSlider"
        android:max="255"/>
    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/blueSlider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/greenSlider"
        android:max="255"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/colorBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

DisplayMessageActivity.java:

```
package com.example.lightcontrol;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean[] buttons = intent.getBooleanArrayExtra(Controller.SELECTED_BUTTONS);

        // Create the text view
        String message = "";
        int i = 0;
        for(boolean currButton: buttons) {
            if(currButton) {
               message += Integer.toString(i) + ",";
            }
            i++;
        }

        final SeekBar redSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.redSlider);
        final SeekBar blueSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.blueSlider);
        final SeekBar greenSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.greenSlider);

        ArrayList<SeekBar> seekArray = new ArrayList<SeekBar>();
        seekArray.add(redSlider);
        seekArray.add(blueSlider);
        seekArray.add(greenSlider);
        for (SeekBar slider : seekArray) {
            slider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                int progress = 0;

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar slider, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                    updateColorBox();
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar slider) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar slider) {
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public void updateColorBox() {
        SeekBar redSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.redSlider);
        SeekBar blueSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.blueSlider);
        SeekBar greenSlider = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.greenSlider);
        TextView colorBox = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.colorBox);

        int redProgress = redSlider.getProgress();
        int blueProgress = blueSlider.getProgress();
        int greenProgress = greenSlider.getProgress();
        String hex = String.format("%02x%02x%02x", redProgress, greenProgress, blueProgress);

        colorBox.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hex));
    }
}
```

Does anyone know why that DisplayMessageActivity pane is blank?  It isn't blank in my xml Design preview tab...Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a call to `setContentView()` in `onCreate()`

Comment: Thanks Danail!  I must have missed that when adapting the tutorial.  Any idea on why setPressed isn't working?

Comment: I think it doesn't work, because the pressed state is modified internally when the button is being clicked / released. There is a discussion you mind find useful here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975168/android-button-setpressed-after-onclick